# Cannot Start Service Squid in Ubuntu Server

Tags: squid, transparent-proxy

[Squid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbrQ4.png)
I'm trying to start my service in squid start but somehow it occurs like:

/etc/init.d/squid 192: --pidfile : not found

/etc/init.d/squid 194" --exec : not found

the squid is already running but somehow the service won't start it occurs  "FAIL"

Here's my /etc/init.d/squid config at Gdrive.

[Squid Config Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XtRsT6-gPsm6ba6DIh0byFM9scIYvXW5/view?usp=sharing)

is there any solutions?

Comment: what if `sudo systemctl restart squid`

Comment: i tried Service Squid Restart instead but still occurs "fail"

Comment: plz show logs `sudo journalctl -u squid`

Comment: this's what it shows

--Logs begin at Wed 2021-01-13 18:27:08 WIB , end at Wed 2021-01-13 18:27:08 WIB --